# Delay in production environment to show ajax progress?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

Is it OK to use threading.sleep in an intranet web application to display AJAX loading (in production environment)? Off course, the application works fine without it but all works too quick for the end user or even a developer to notice any difference.

What is the recommended approach ?

Comment: hmm, well at least do it client-side (setTimeout), not server-side.

Comment: Why would somebody want to make their application slow?

Comment: Due to flickering of progress bars and status messages.

Answer (score 1):

Just read this thread: I am amazed: you want an application to fetch data slower? That sounds really strange to me.
You should try to make it clear to the user that the new data is loaded. You can use an animation or something like a highlight color for new items. Maybe a 'new' icon?

Imagine that the servers are running slow deu to some errors. Than the user still has to wait an extra second to see the data. Just something to think about.

Comment: Since it is operating on intranet, all progress bars are merely just a flicker, which is more annoying to the users.

Comment: So either we remove them or show them only after a certain period of time is passed.